# Gray box on Users Page?

Tags: support, profile-page

On the users tab page there is a gray box in the mid upper right. A long time ago i believe it was used to show user statistics change over time. Now i see noting. Is this common among other SO, SF, MSO, and SU users? I have tried viewing the page in IE and Firefox with the same results.

Comment: IIRC, I don't think this box has ever been used for user statistics.  There have been requests for additional user statistics in the profile page, but not, I think, in the gray box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's your Biography/About field. If you edit your profile, you can write stuff in it.