# What's the blank space on my About Me page meant for?

Tags: support, profile-page

When I look at my profile, I see this area with a highlighted background color in most browsers (Internet Explorer, Firefox, and Chrome).

Does this convey any specific information?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19053/gray-box-on-users-page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fill it with info about you.  Check out any of the users' profiles on the [first users page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users) for some good examples.