# What is the big gray box next to my profile?

Tags: support, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gray box on Users Page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19053/gray-box-on-users-page)

Next to my profile info, there's a big gray rectangle with nothing inside. Initially, I thought it was some ad blocked by AdBlock but there's still nothing even after disabling it. Any idea what it is for?

Comment: You're not the first person to be confused about what this box is for... How can we improve the discoverability of this feature? It seems quite intuitive to me; fill in the "about me" section when editing your profile, and the text magically appears.

Comment: I thought it was intuitive too, but maybe instead of an empty box there could be some instruction along the lines of "Tell us about yourself" that links to the profile editor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the *About Me* box where you can write something about yourself. Click the [*edit*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/edit/166973) link which appears on the right top of [your profile information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/166973/laurent) and head to the bottom for the texarea where you can fill/edit it.

Look at the profiles of [other (active) users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users), you'll see that the majority of them have filled it in.